# No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:ex;databaseName=Cities_names

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans, netbeans-8

I' trying to connect a db and showing with combobox in NetBeans I have this as output:

> SEVERE: null
> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:DESKTOP-4N1HNP8;databaseName=Cities_names
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
> at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
> at com.mycompany.acam.Panel1.Fillcombo(Panel1.java:31)
> at com.mycompany.acam.Panel1.(Panel1.java:27)
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> at com.mycompany.acam.Panel1.Fillcombo(Panel1.java:46) //con.close();
> at com.mycompany.acam.Panel1.(Panel1.java:27) //Fillcombo();
>
> The POM for mssql:mssql-jdbc:jar:9.4.1 is missing, no dependency information available

Here is where I connect to the database and where I fill the combobox:

```
public class Panel1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    static Connection con;
    static ResultSet rs;
    static PreparedStatement pst;
    static Statement st;

    public Panel1() {
        initComponents();
        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        Fillcombo();
    }

    public  void Fillcombo() {
        try {
           con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:DESKTOP-4N1HNP8;databaseName=Cities_names", "Stefan", "stefan");
           String Query = "SELECT * FROM Cities_names";
           st = con.createStatement();
           pst = con.prepareStatement(Query);
           rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

           while (rs.next())
           {
               Combo_box.addItem(rs.getString("City"));
           }

           Combo_box.setSelectedItem(null);
      } catch(SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(Panel1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
      }
      finally {
          try {
             con.close();
             pst.close();
             rs.close();
          } catch(SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(Panel1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE,null,ex);
          }
    }
}
```

The dependency from pom.xml -maven:

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mssql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I added dependency from  dependencies node.I installed manually the jar file.

Comment: Update : I change :con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver:DESKTOP-4N1HNP8;databaseName=Cities_names", "Stefan", "stefan"); into : con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-4N1HNP8;databaseName=Cities_names", "Stefan", "stefan"); and now i receive this: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near 'Cities_names'.

Answer (score 0):

I changed:

```
String Query = "SELECT * FROM Cities_names";
```

to:

```
String Query = "SELECT TOP (1000) [City] FROM [Cities_names].[dbo]. [Cities]";
```

and it's working <3